# How I solve this simple problem with CodeBlock?

Tags: c, reference, codeblocks

I'm a beginner and have 3 file to sum recursive an array.

**array.h**

```
int sum(int n, int a[]);
void create_array(int n, int a[]);
```

**array.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"
void create_array(int n, int a[]){
    int i;
    for( i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Inserire il %d elemento dell'array\n",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int sum(int n, int a[]){
    if(n>0){
        return a[n-1]+sum(n-1,a);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "array.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Inserire la dimensione dell'array\n");
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    create_array(n,a);
    int res=sum(n,a);
    printf("La somma degli elementi e' %d\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

***PROBLEMS***

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
undefined reference to `create_array'|
undefined reference to `sum'|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

I have put these 2 files in the same directory. 
If I compile and run them with terminal cmd Windows they started.
But if I try to compile from IDE CodeBlocks says this errors.
Anyone help?

Comment: Did you add main.c and array.c to the project? Also, always use header guards: `#ifndef ARRAY_H #define ARRAY_H /* header file contents here */ #endif`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with the way you've told Code::Blocks that these files are all related.

### What I did:

■ opened up the IDE and clicked NewFile->Empty File

■ copied the first block of code, pasted it and saved as array.h

■ copied the second block of code, pasted it and saved as array.c

■ copied the third block of code, pasted it and saved as main.c

■ Hit "Build and Run"

### Then got exactly the same set of errors that you did.

What you needed to do instead, was hit New File->Project, select Console Application, select C, enter a project name (the exe will have the same name by default, though you can change this)
From there, you'll get a folder created that contains a .CBP file and a main.c file. You can then hit "New File" and this time, it will ask you if you want to add it to the current project.